# Android App based on a service stop after some time in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

I've created an app, based on this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/services-in-android-with-example/, for playing an audio file than have 10 hours in background. But, after block or minimize, unfortunately, the sound stops after some time.

Do someone have an idea why this happening? Is there a way that keeps the app playing the sound after block or minimize, just like Spotify does?

Comment: Use a foreground service.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for the answer. But, i've already use foreground service in my app, if you could see in the link that i've based my app  :(

Comment: The example in that link does not use a foreground service.

Comment: Can you wait some time? I will make such app and upload it on GitHub. Then you will get the code from there

Comment: Thank you so much @Sambhav.K, certanielly i can wait! :D This app is from playing white noise tha helps my baby daugther sleeps..

Comment: The app is done I guess. Let me test it out now

Comment: Done. The app is completed. I will add it to GitHub now. Just 5-10 mins

Comment: Check my repo in the answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a repo for that app. For now, I have not added features to add controls when the app is running but will be coming soon. But, for now, when the app goes in background, the audio starts playing with the following controls:

1. Start
2. Pause
3. Reset

You can find the repo over [here](https://github.com/sambhav2358/Background-Audio-Player/).

Comment: Thank you so much @Sambhav.K, for your generosity in write the code. Because of your example, i finally understands how a foreground service works. The code works perfectly for me! Thanks again and have a great week!